# CakePHP3 - Parent BelongsTo - Database Error PDOException

Tags: php, pdo, parent, belongs-to, cakephp-3.0

What am i doing wrong here, or is this some kind of Bug?

On TicketsTable.php

```
/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config) {
    $this->table('tickets');
    $this->displayField('title');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp', [
        'events' => [
            'Tickets.closed' => [
                'close_date' => 'always'
            ],
    ]]);
    $this->belongsTo('Registars', [
        'className' => 'Users',
        'foreignKey' => 'registar_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Parents', [
        'className' => 'Tickets',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
    ]);
   }
```

On Controller

```
/**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id Ticket id.
     * @return void
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null) {
        $ticket = $this->Tickets->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Parents', 'Registars']
        ]);
        $this->set('ticket', $ticket);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['ticket']);
    }
```

Error:

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'Tickets'

If you are using SQL keywords as table column names, you can enable identifier quoting for your database connection in config/app.php.

SQL Query:

SELECT Tickets.id AS `Tickets__id`, Tickets.parent_id AS `Tickets__parent_id`, Tickets.title AS `Tickets__title`, Tickets.description AS `Tickets__description`, Tickets.registar_id AS `Tickets__registar_id`, Tickets.type_id AS `Tickets__type_id`, Tickets.origin_id AS `Tickets__origin_id`, Tickets.origin_date AS `Tickets__origin_date`, Tickets.process_id AS `Tickets__process_id`, Tickets.activity_id AS `Tickets__activity_id`, Tickets.category_id AS `Tickets__category_id`, Tickets.supplier_id AS `Tickets__supplier_id`, Tickets.safety_id AS `Tickets__safety_id`, Tickets.priority_id AS `Tickets__priority_id`, Tickets.approved AS `Tickets__approved`, Tickets.approve_user_id AS `Tickets__approve_user_id`, Tickets.close_date AS `Tickets__close_date`, Tickets.close_user_id AS `Tickets__close_user_id`, Tickets.comment AS `Tickets__comment`, Tickets.status_id AS `Tickets__status_id`, Tickets.modified_user_id AS `Tickets__modified_user_id`, Tickets.modified AS `Tickets__modified`, Tickets.created AS `Tickets__created`, Users.id AS `Users__id`, Users.name AS `Users__name`, Users.username AS `Users__username`, Users.password AS `Users__password`, Users.email AS `Users__email`, Users.active AS `Users__active`, Users.modified AS `Users__modified`, Users.created AS `Users__created` FROM tickets Tickets LEFT JOIN tickets Tickets ON Tickets.id = (Tickets.parent_id) LEFT JOIN users Users ON Users.id = (Tickets.registar_id) WHERE Tickets.id = :c0 LIMIT 1

Comment: You are using `Tickets` as alias two times. Change one to `Tickets2` or something.

Comment: the SQL Query is created by the ORM on CAKEPHP 3 framework, so i think this is a problem on my TicketsTable.php settings or in the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work out of the box, the joined in tables should be aliased properly as `Registars` and `Parents`, and for sure this worked until recently, so yes, this is a bug, possibly related to **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/5836**

Please report this as an issue over at [**GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues).

**Udate** Actually it seems that this has already been reported: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5882**

Comment: Thank you, i shoud start looking at cake issues before stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your belongs to association classname as follows

```
$this->belongsTo('Registars', [
        'className' => 'Registars',
        'foreignKey' => 'registar_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Parents', [
        'className' => 'Parents',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
    ]);
```

1. 'className' => 'Users' should be 'className' => 'Registars'
2. 'className' => 'Tickets', should be  'className' => 'Parents'

Thanks